# Changing Windows language programatically

Tags: windows, script, input-languages

I have multiple input languages in my Windows XP: English and Hebrew. I use both of them.

I want to make a script that will programmatically switch to English. (If that's hard to do, a workaround might be to programatically press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>, if that's possible.)

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any correct programmatic way of doing this, but it's pretty easy to fake out pressing a key. Here is a PowerShell script that does that:

> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
>   [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%+")

**EDIT**:

I found out a better way to do this programmatically, essentially using the `LoadKeyboardLayout` and `ActivateKeyboardLayout` functions. I'll admit, it isn't very easy to script.